# How to have a custom command prompt in zsh?

Tags: debian, zsh, prompt

How to have a command prompt in zsh?

This is what I want to have -

```
[username@host]-[short-directory-path]-[time]$
```

Currently it just gives hostname with a different prompt -

```
think-debian% hostname
think-debian
```

Can somebody help?

Update - I had read the zsh manpage in the sense that I skimmed through it, saw that there are whole lot of sections which means different manpages. I did grep/using regular expression for PS1 using `/` and using `PS1` as pattern in quite a few of the manpages and not finding anything hence put it above.

Comment: Read `man zsh`, look for `PS1`.

Comment: I had read in the sense that I skimmed through it, saw that there are whole lot of sections. I did grep/using regular expression for `PS1` using `\` and using `PS1` as pattern in quite a few of the manpages before putting it above.

Comment: @waltinator updated my query with what I had done.

Comment: A simple search lead me to `man zshmisc`, the `EXPANSION OF PROMPT SEQUENCES` section.

Comment: thanx, saw that, now how do I run that once to see if the command prompt looks like what I want. Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1):

As you mention you set the PS1 environment variable.  I believe you would want

```
export PS1="\u@\h-\W-\A"
```

you can set that and then see if it displays what you want.  If so, add that to one of your shell startup files (like `.zshrc`).  If it is not exactly what you want then tweak it using information from the zsh man pages.

Comment: actually had done that. Now I can't find .zshrc file anymore, see the other question that you had tried to answer. http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/332429/how-do-have-a-directory-under-which-i-have-all-zsh-related-files

Answer (score 0):

Zsh and Bash are different. For zsh try this:

```
[username@host]-[short-directory-path]-[time]$

export PROMPT='[${ret_status}%{$fg[magenta]%}%n@%{$fg[red]%}%m]-[%{$fg[cyan]%}%c%{$reset_color%}]%{$fg_bold[blue]%}-[%T]%{$reset_color%}$ '
```