# How do have a directory under which I have all .zsh related files

Tags: debian, zsh

I want to keep all .z files of zsh under a directory. Is there a way to do that, if yes, how ?

The two files I see are -

```
 $ ls .z
.zcompdump  .zshrc
```

Could there be anymore. Could I just put a directory, call it .zsh and dump these files in it or would there be something more than that. I have no idea what .zcompdump is supposed to do -

A listing of the contents inside gives me this -

```
$ head .zcompdump
#files: 823 version: 5.3

_comps=(
'-' '_torsocks'
'.' '_source'
'5g' '_go'
'5l' '_go'
'6g' '_go'
'6l' '_go'
'8g' '_go'
```

If I'm not wrong, it seems to be some sort of completion (similar to what bash-completion did) or am I reading it wrong.

Looking to know more.

Update - This is what I have done -

```
/etc/zsh $ tail zshenv          
# output or assume the shell is attached to a tty.
#
# Global Order: zshenv, zprofile, zshrc, zlogin

if [[ -z "$PATH" || "$PATH" == "/bin:/usr/bin" ]]
then
    export PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/games"
fi

export ZDOTDIR="/home/shirish/.zsh/"
```

Then in /home/shirish -

```
/home/shirish $  mv .zcompdump .zsh/
/home/shirish $ mv .zshrc .zsh/
```

Then I went to .zsh/ expecting the two dot files to appear there but didn't see them -

```
/home/shirish/.zsh $ ls -lh 
total 0
```

Am confused by what went wrong.

Comment: It is a duplicate but not quite as I actually got some more information about what zdotdir does among other things. The other answer didn't have this explained well.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way, if you are root on the machine, would be to put the following your your /etc/zshenv file:

export ZDOTDIR="/path/to/where/you/want/zsh/files"

To verify that Debian does read/process the /etc/zshenv file to a "man zsh" on the system and look in the FILES section of the man page.  If so, and if that file does not exist, then you can create it.

Comment: there is no /etc/zshenv file. This is a file I will have to create ?

Comment: actually it sits in `/etc/zsh/zshenv`

Comment: See my updated question, maybe the above I did is correct or not, does it seem correct ?